# A variation on the local Günther inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

This question is about a variation on the Günther (also known as Günther-Bishop) inequality for manifolds of sectional curvature bounded from above. With Greg Kuperberg, we would deduce from it a conjectured isoperimetric inequality in dimension $4$ which for the moment we only get for small enough domains; see [our paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3115) for more details and below for a short account.

### Notation and the precise question

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, and let us call "candle function" at $x\in M$ the Jacobian of its exponential map, normalized as the function $j_x:Tx M \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$ \mathrm{d}y = j_x(tu) \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}u \quad\mbox{when }y=\exp_x(tu)$$
where $\mathrm{d}y$ is the Riemannian volume, $\mathrm{d}t$ is Lebesgue measure, and $\mathrm{d}u$ is the Riemannian volume of the unit ball of $T_x M$.

Fix a geodesic segment $\gamma$ of length $\ell$, parametrized by arc length, without conjugate points, and consider the function of two parameters $r\le t$ given by
$$j(r,t) = j_{\gamma(r)}\big((t-r)\gamma'(r)\big)$$
that is, $j(r,t)$ represent how large the volume element at $\gamma(t)$ looks in the exponential chart based at $\gamma(r)$.

For example, if we denote by $s$ be the function $j$ when $M$ is the hyperbolic space, we get
$$ s(r,t) = \sinh^{n-1}(t-r).$$

The question is the following:

> Is it true that when $M$ has sectional curvature bounded above by $-1$,
>   then (for all geodesic as above) the expression
>   $$ j(0,\ell) - (n-1) \int_0^\ell j(0,t) \,\mathrm{d}t - (n-1) \int_0^\ell j(r,\ell) \,\mathrm{d}t +(n-1)^2 \int_0^\ell \int_0^t j(r,t) \,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}t$$
>   is minimized when $j=s$, i.e. when the curvature is equal to $-1$ along the geodesic?

The $n=4$ version would be enough for our purpose, but I don't see why it would be easier than the general case.

We conjecture that a stronger inequality, obtained by differentiating twice the above, should be true:

> Is it true that when $M$ has sectional curvature bounded above by $-1$,
>   then (for all geodesic as above) the expression
>   $$ -\partial^2_{rt} j  -(n-1) \partial_t j +(n-1) \partial_r j +(n-1)^2 j$$
>   is minimized when $j=s$, i.e. when the curvature is equal to $-1$ along the geodesic?

(here for example $\partial^2_{rt}$ means $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\partial t}$)

### Comparison with Günther, and what we know

A local version of Günther's inequality is that when $M$ has sectional curvature bounded above by $-1$,
$$ \partial_t j / j $$
is minimized when $j=s$. It is easy to derive from this that then
$$ \partial_t j - (n-1) j$$
is minimized when $j=s$. So in a sense, what we ask is to improve this comparison from the operator $\partial_t -(n-1)$ to the operator $(-\partial_r -(n-1))(\partial_t-(n-1))$.

We are able to answer positively our question when $n=2$, but our proofs do not extend to higher dimension, at least not easily. We are also able to prove the above with weaker constants instead of the $(n-1)$, but then we get a smallness constraint when we apply the inequality to get the isoperimetric comparison.

In our paper with Greg, we prove that if the above inequality is true, then whenever $n=4$, $M$ is simply connected and has sectional curvature bounded above by $-1$, the isoperimetric profile of $M$ is bounded below by the isoperimetric profile of the $4$-dimensional hyperbolic space. A similar comparison is conjectured in all dimension and also when comparing with Euclidean space (with of course the assumption that sectional curvature is non-positive). This conjecture is known to be true when $n=2$ (Weil 1926, ... Aubin 70's ) or $3$ (Kleiner 1992), and for the Euclidean comparison when $n=4$ (Croke 1984). Right now, we only get the $n=4$, curvature less than $-1$ case for domains of volume less than an explicit constant, due to the limited solution we have to the present question. Note that we get a fully satisfying version of this conjecture for comparison to a sphere.

Comment: the first highlighted question is for the bounty yes? the second just a conjecture? Or do you want a proof of both? Also, in the first Q, the last integral has *t* as both a limit and a variable - is this a typo?

Comment: An answer of the first question in the case $n=4$ would get the bounty. There is no typo there, read $\int_0^\ell \Big(\int_0^t j(r,t) \,dr\Big) \,dt$ or equivalently $\iint_{0\le r\le t\le \ell} j(r,t) \,dr\,dt$.

Comment: what do you mean by **s**? I can only see an example function, not a technical definition.here ''for example $∂2rt$ means $∂2∂r∂s$) ''- is this a typo ('t' becomes 's'). Thanks. (typo from just before 'Comparison with Günther, and what we know')

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: the $s$ in the partial derivative was indeed a typo, thank you. The function $s$ is defined just before the first question: it is the candle function of the hyperbolic space (for any geodesic, as the hyperbolic space is two-point homogeneous).

Comment: Maybe a look at this paper could help you http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?pid=ensmat-001:1992:38::194

Comment: @BS.: this paper looks interesting; it might be possible to use it to reduce the matricial problem to a scalar problem, which is basically the case we know how to handle. Otal's paper only works with one derivative though, so it will need some work to see how it goes.

Comment: the integral of sinh is cosh which is an even function.

Comment: also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry#Sectional_curvature_bounded_above; and also m inimize x+1/x

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: I sure know that cosh is an antiderivative of sinh, and I don't quite see your points. This question lies quite beyond the content of wikipedia.

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: yes, I am sure that I don't see your point, and that the very classical properties of non-positively curved manifolds stated on wikipedia (which does not even mentions the classical Günther inequality) do not answer my question. Now, if you claim to have a solution, you are very welcome to propose it and I would be more than happy to give the bounty if it stands right. But throwing obvious facts without apparent relation to the question is useless.

Comment: I was looking at the (−∂r−(n−1))(∂t−(n−1)) angle - which i got as far as 'if f(X) and g(X) and minimum, is f(x)g(x) minimized by X'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23883/discussion-between-benoit-kloeckner-and-jon-mark-perry).